# Dispatcher - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, okhttp

When executing this function, the following error appears:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
```

How to solve?

```
fun run(url: String) {
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            Log.i("Falha", e.toString())
        }
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {

            val json= response.body?.string()

            val jsonArray = JSONTokener(json).nextValue() as JSONArray


            for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {

                val x = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nomeParque")
                val y = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("morada")
                val lat = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("latitude").toDouble()
                val lng = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitude").toDouble()

                nome.set(i, x)
                morada.set(i, y)
                latitude.set(i, lat)
                longitude.set(i, lng)

            }

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add -1 in jsonArray.length() in the for sentence.